# sudo and git problem in Kali Linux used in VM in Windows 10

Tags: bash, sudo, kali-linux, git

I have Windows 10. Now I have installed VM and in it; I have installed Kali Linux.

But the problem is that whenever I try to put git or sudo commands it shows

```
-bash: sudo: command not found 
-bash: git: command not found
```

What to do? It even doesn't work in Windows terminal.

Comment: https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/#:~:text=The%20fact%20of%20the%20matter,general%2Dpurpose%20Linux%20desktop%20distribution

Answer (score 0):

> -bash: sudo: command not found

You are using a kali version prior to 2020.1 , `sudo` isn't installed by default. To install it:

```
# apt install sudo
```

> -bash: git: command not found

`git` isn't installed by default, to install it:

```
# apt install git
```

**Starting from kali 2020.1** root access has been dropped, users must use `sudo`.

To Enable/Disable **password-less privilege escalation** on kali-linux you need to install the `kali-grant-root` package :

```
$ sudo apt install kali-grant-root
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure kali-grant-root
```

> With 2020.1 Kali has swapped to a privileged non-root user by default. This means that root has no password set, and the account created during installation is the one to use. It is possible to re-enable access to the root user, however this is not recommended.
>
> ## Sudo on Kali
>
> Because Kali creates a user with administrative privileges by default, users can use sudo right away and supply their password for authentication. Should a user wish to enable password-less sudo, which poses a security risk should someone gain access the the user account, they have that option.

```
sudo apt install -y kali-grant-root && sudo dpkg-reconfigure kali-grant-root
```

> The previous command installs a package that will allow for a user to be added to a trusted group that will not need to supply a password when using `sudo`. This does not mean however that root will be reinstated.

Kali linux docs:

- [All about sudo](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/sudo/)